# git fetch on a bundle produces no output

Tags: git

I have a bundle which I am attempting to merge into another tree. I created the bundle with

```
git bundle create changes.bundle b88452317246ec2893c66b..HEAD
```

When on the target I issue

```
git fetch -v changes.bundle
```

there is no output at all and nothing changes.

On a different repository on the same system exactly the same procedure works perfectly. What could be the difference? I am using Git 1.7.1 on RHEL 6.1

Comment: Try running `git bundle verify ./changes.bundle` and note what `HEAD` points to.  Also, several issues have been fixed since 1.7.1 was released.  One involved a `git bundle create` producing a bad bundle with long subjects (I'd expect an error though), and an issue where `git fetch` wasn't producing progress output for a large bundle.  I'd still expect to see `HEAD -> FETCH_HEAD` in the output on the last one, but it's possible that it didn't show it due to the bug.  Can you also run `git rev-parse FETCH_HEAD` after running `git fetch`?  Does it match `HEAD` in the bundle?

Comment: Thanks for your help.  

Here's the output from git bundle verify:  
    $ git bundle verify ../fitnesse.bundle  
    The bundle contains 1 ref  
    fe6107724d0b4c5e38e2b5a69db11bd8f27bc43d HEAD  
    The bundle requires these 1 ref  
    3a977d5a1479d87a4b9ff152e1f9631119b89311 Initial commit  
    ../fitnesse.bundle is okay  

The referenced commit is correct.  

With git rev-parse FETCH_HEAD I get  
    fatal: ambiguous argument 'FETCH_HEAD': unknown revision or path now in the working tree.  
    Use '--' to separate paths from revisions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went back and compiled v1.7.1 of Git to try a few things out.  This appears that it was a bug in Git.  The actual commit that fixed this bug was [`3ee1757baeecb6fe6c8b2446b3afe0519584b63f`](https://github.com/gitster/git/commit/3ee1757baeecb6fe6c8b2446b3afe0519584b63f).  The issue is that the fetch command was mishandling the URL argument when there was a remote tracking branch configured.  The fix came in Git v1.7.3.

You can work around the issue by providing a refspec.  Probably the easiest thing to do would be this:

```
$ git fetch changes.bundle HEAD:tmp-branch
$ git merge --ff --ff-only tmp-branch
$ git branch -d tmp-branch
```

That will stash the changes to HEAD into a new branch called `tmp-branch`.  Fast-forward your current branch to include it (it will fail if it can't fast-forward... it's up to you to resolve that either by merging or rebasing).  Then the last command deletes the temporary branch.